# How can I verify that Google Analytics 4's gtag function and dataLayer were processed correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-4

Is there a way to verify that calls to `gtag` were processed? And on failure, perhaps try a re-transmit or do some other handling? I know I can put a test order through and watch the data, but I need something that works for all users on the site, not just me doing a test.

We are using `gtag.js` to tag and track our ecommerce site. I've found that a small percentage of ecommerce orders are not tracked (maybe 3% - 5%). We also have screen-capture recordings set up, and on several of the untracked orders, I've been able to view the users' session recordings, and I verified that their browser loaded the final transaction page without a problem, and no errors were shown in the console. This rules out any weird/random javascript errors.

So I'd like to monitor the call to `gtag` and verify that Google did in fact receive the `purchase` event. Then maybe if it fails, or if x amount of seconds goes by without a response, I'll re-transmit. Is that possible?

I read through google's docs on the Google tag (https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference) and they don't seem to indicate that it has a response when you send an event.

But maybe there's some obscure way to do it?

Here's some source code, keep in mind that this successfully tracks at least 95% of orders, so I'm not expecting a review for some major undiscovered bug.. Just hoping for an enhancement that re-transmits the purchase event if Google doesn't receive it..

In the `head` tag of the site we have the following:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXX');
</script>
```

And on our invoice page we have the following. We use Miva Merchant as our ecommerce system, the `mvt` stuff is handled by the ecommerce system (looping through item list, data replaced by the corresponding values, etc):

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    currency: 'USD',
    transaction_id: '&mvt:order:id;',
    value: '&mvt:order:total;',
    affiliation: 'Company Name',
    shipping: '&mvt:global:shippingCharge;',
    tax: '&mvt:global:taxCharge;',
    items: [
        /* <mvt:foreach iterator="item" array="order:items"> */
            {
                item_id: '&mvt:item:code;',
                item_name: '&mvt:item:code;',
                item_category: '',
                price: '&mvt:item:price;',
                quantity: '&mvt:item:quantity;'
            },
        /* </mvt:foreach> */
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chatted with google support about this today, and long story short, the result is that either:

> A) there is no way to monitor/verify the outcome of the `gtag` call
> (and subsequent `window.dataLayer` handling)
>
> B) the rep didn't understand what I was asking, so they made up a fake answer
>
> C) the rep understood what I was asking but didn't know the real
> answer and didn't  feel like looking into it further, so they made up a fake answer
>
> D) the rep didn't know what they were talking about

Either way, I had to come up with something on my own, so I did some research to see if I could just monitor all network requests and filter for ones to `analytics.google.com`. That would tell me that the user's browser attempted to send data to google, which is better than nothing. For example, now I would know that the `gtag` > `window.dataLayer` > `tell google` sequence was working.

Here's what I came up with:

```
let analyticsCalls = [];
let monitorGoogleAnalytics = () => {
    let newRequestFound = false;
    window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource").filter(request=>{
        return (
            request.initiatorType === "beacon" &&
            request.name.indexOf("analytics.google.com") !== -1
        );
    }).map((request,index)=>{
        // looks like a request to google analytics, have we logged this index already?
        if ( !analyticsCalls[index] ) {
            // nope we haven't, add it to our list
            analyticsCalls.push(request);
            newRequestFound = true;
        }
    });
    if ( newRequestFound ) {
        console.log("at least one new call has been detected");
        console.log("analyticsCalls",analyticsCalls);
        /* now do with this what you will. For example, check every call, and
        * if 30 seconds goes by and you still don't see a call that has your purchase event,
        * try to send it again, perhaps with slightly different data
        */
    }
}; // monitorGoogleAnalytics

setInterval(()=>{
    monitorGoogleAnalytics();
}, 1000);
```

If you're using `React`, it would probably be a good idea to put this in a `useEffect` and return a function that clears the interval.